# Pulling an data from a nested INSERT statement using SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, insert

Is it possible to have an INSERT statement return the columns affected into a SELECT statement?
For example, I have the statement:

```
INSERT INTO work_day (WorkDateId, TimeframeId) VALUES (@selecteddateid,@timeframeid);
```

But work_day has an auto incrementing, work_dayId, that gets created when this row  data is inserted. I want to put this work_dayId in another statement, but I was wondering if it would be able to nest this INSERT inside a SELECT that will select the affected/created row.

So would I be able to place this statement like so:

```
INSERT INTO appointment 
(customerid, WorkDayId, UserId, Priority, Assign)
VALUES 
(@otherdata
(SELECT WorkDayId FROM work_day WHERE WorkDateId = (INSERT INTO work_day (WorkDateId, TimeframeId) VALUES (@selecteddateid,@timeframeid))));
```

Comment: No, you cannot do that.  You want `last_insert_id()`.

Comment: Holy crap! That's SO much easier. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS @Gordon stated:

> No, you cannot do that. You want `last_insert_id()`

Posting it here as an answer for better visibility.